# Space-time tradeoff lower bounds

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, big-list, space-time-tradeoff

Following the discussion on lower bounds for 3SAT [[1](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/93/what-are-the-best-current-lower-bounds-on-3sat)], I'm wondering what are the main lower bound results formulated as space-time tradeoffs.  I'm excluding results such as, say, Savitch's theorem; a good entry would focus on a single problem and its bounds.  An example would be :

"Let T and S be the running time and space bound of any SAT algorithm. Then we must have T⋅S≥n2cos(π/7)−o(1) infinitely often." (Given in [[1](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/93/what-are-the-best-current-lower-bounds-on-3sat)] by Ryan Williams.)

or

"SAT cannot be solved simultaneously in n<sup>1+0(1)</sup> time and
n<sup>1-ε</sup> space for any ε>0 on general
random-access nondeterministic Turing machines." (Lance Fortnow in 10.1109/CCC.1997.612300)

Further, I'm including *definitions* of natural space-time tradeoff complexity classes (excluding circuit classes).

Comment: hmm. another example of not needing the CW tag.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Suresh is saying that you don't have to put "community wiki" on this question, if you rephrase the question to be something other than a big list, and were more specific about what you're looking for. Also, is it really a "soft question"?

Comment: Well, I do want a big list, and the question not being specific is, I think, a good way to get one.  Is this kind of list prohibited?  (I can pretty much deduce that I did something wrong, as no answer has been given, but don't know what.)
Also, this is a soft question as it doesn't require any intellectual work.

Comment: We hope to clarify this eventually in the FAQ. I'd say that this is not a soft question because it's technical. A soft question is more about topics around research - where to go to grad school, how to read papers, etc

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are a few additional references. More can be found by looking at the papers that cite these.

[Duris and Galil (1984)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=0738748) give a language in $P$ which requires $T^2 S \geq \Omega(n^3)$ on one-tape Turing machines with any constant number of read-write heads. [Karchmer (1986)](http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/0304397586901507) showed that the same lower bound holds for the *element distinctness* problem.

[Babai, Nisan, and Szegedy (1989)](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=73007.73008) give a very natural language (generalized inner product) that is solvable in $O(n)$ time and $O(1)$ space on a $k+1$-head one-tape Turing machine, that requires $T S \geq \Omega(n^2)$ on any $k$-head one-tape Turing machine.

[Ajtai (1999)](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=301424) shows time-space tradeoffs for deterministic random access machines computing element distinctness. In particular if $S \leq o(n)$, then $T \geq \omega(n)$. Subsequent work by [Beame, Saks, Sun, and Vee (2000)](http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/beame/papers/randomts.ps) proves time-space tradeoffs for randomized computations.

[Santhanam (2001)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0020-0190%2800%2900227-1) showed that $TS \geq \Omega(n^2)$ holds for multitape Turing machines solving SAT, building on Cobham's analogous lower bound for PALINDROMES.