# Space-time tradeoff and the best algorithm

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, open-problem, space-time-tradeoff

Consider some language $L$ such that:

$L \in DTIME(O(f(n))) \cap DSPACE(O(g(n)))$

and so that

$L \not\in DTIME(o(f(n))) \cup DSPACE(o(g(n)))$

In other words, the fastest machine $M$ computes $L$ in time $O(f(n))$ and the most space efficient machine $M'$ computes $L$ while using space $O(g(n))$.

What can be said about the space efficiency of M or the time efficiency of M'? Or more precisely, if $\mathbb{M}_T$ is the set of all machines that compute $L$ in $O(f(n))$ then what can we say about the most space efficient machine in $\mathbb{M}_T$? What about the same thing for the obvious space version: $\mathbb{M}_S$.

Alternatively, can $f(n)$ and $g(n)$ be used to define some good space-time tradeoffs? Under what conditions is $TS \in o(f(n)g(n))$ or more generally for some space-time tradeoff $h(T,S)$ under what conditions is $h(T,S) \in h(o(f(n)),o(g(n)))$.

Comment: Are you asking about an arbitrary L, or are you interested in results of this nature that might exist for specific problems ?

Comment: I am interested in both, really. My original motivation was mostly from reachability problems (directed and undirected st-connectivity). However, it would be interesting to know if there are any general bounds or techniques available.

Comment: So, take any decidable language $L$.  This language gives functions $f_L, g_L$ so that $L \in \text{TIME}[f_L(n)] \cap \text{SPACE}[g_L(n)]$ and $L \not\in \text{TIME}[o(f_L(n))] \cup \text{SPACE}[o(g_L(n))]$.  (Is this true, or are there "speedup" languages that violate it?)

Comment: Specifically, there are examples in range searching of problems that admit (Query, Space) of the form (log n, poly(n)), or (sublinear, linear), or any interpolation thereof

Comment: @Derrick: I am not exactly sure what you are asking, or if you are restating my question. For a given language $L$ the functions $f_L$ and $g_L$ can (hopefully) be thought of as defined (although obviously finding these functions is way harder than the P vs. NP problem). But I don't think it means that there exists a machine M that solves L that achieves BOTH speed $O(f_L)$ and $O(g_L)$. It just means that there exist machines $M_T$ and $M_S$ for $L$ so that the runtime of $M_T$ is $O(f_L(n))$ and space use of $M_S$ is $O(g_L(N))$. I am not sure what you mean by a "speedup" language.

Comment: @Suresh: could you elaborate on your comment? Does you mean there are machines M and M' for some range search problem with M having time $O(log n)$ and space $O(poly(n))$ (but not linear) and M' having time $O(f(n))$ for some $f(n) \in o(n) - O(log n)$ and space $O(n)$?

Comment: I was trying to restate, specifically pointing out that $f$ and $g$ depend on $L$.  I also wanted to ask if EVERY language admits such $f$ and $g$, which may not be true.

Comment: @Artem, yes, that's correct, and in fact for any tradeoff between these two as well. If that's the kind of thing you're interested in, I can post an answer.

Comment: Related?  [Space-time tradeoff lower bounds](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/832/space-time-tradeoff-lower-bounds)

Comment: Do I miss something or is your restriction analoguous to $L \in DTIME(\Theta(f(n))) \cap DSPACE(\Theta(g(n)))$?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The prototypical f and g here would probably be poly-time and polylog space.  The interesting problem here is connectivity (in directed graphs) which can be solved in polynomial time (using linear space) or in polylog space (using super-polynomial time).  It is a famous open problem whether it can be solved in TIME-SPACE(poly,polylog), a class known as [SC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SC_%28complexity%29).

I.e. your question is a well-known open problem.  I don't think that anything non-trivial is known here.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was suspecting it would be an open problem, but hoping that some specific results would be know already. Unfortunate :(.

Answer (score -4):

this question turned up on "similar questions" when I just posted this other question https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/9677/deterministic-time-space-separation-via-space-compression.

there I cite hopcroft,paul,valiants 1977 result (apparently best known acc. to rj lipton in his blog) that seems to apply to your question ie $\mathsf{DTIME}(t(n)) \subseteq \mathsf{DSPACE}(t(n)/log(n))$

Comment: I don't see how this applies to time-space trade-offs...

Comment: the concept of "time space tradeoff" seems not to be exactly defined. my answer can be understood as follows: a program that is in DTIME(t(n)) is "naturally" in DSPACE(t(n)). the HPV1977 results then allow one to construct a TM, at the expense of some increase in states (and tapes maybe?) such that it takes DSPACE(t(n)/log(n)) space instead. therefore a "tradeoff"

Comment: There is a standard understanding of trade-offs in CS which is not at all what you describe (what you describe is not a trade-off at all, but just a standard relationship between DTIME and DSPACE). Further, I explicitly explain what I want in time-space trade-off in my question, please read questions carefully before trying to answer them.

Comment: if your definition of time-space tradeoffs above in your question is standard as you say, is it defined in any literature?

Comment: looking over your definition it looks intuitively plausible that such f(n),g(n) exist for all decidable languages but wouldnt one run into problems even proving such f(n),g(n) necessarily exist due to the blum speedup theorem....?

Comment: actually one statement of the blum speed up thm is that "there exist decidable languages with no fastest machine". therefore I think your functions can be proven not to exist for some decidable languages (re derrick stolee's comment above) – vzn 33 mins ago

Comment: the issue of time/space tradeoffs has always been a question for me but wonder if expressing it is actually somewhat "open" and theoretical CS has not well nailed it down yet. fyi I am reading [goldreich's discussion of the hierarchy thms & blums speedup thm](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~oded/cc-drafts.html) (one of the better online referencees) & think you need to add the condition that f,g are time,space constructible respectively to avoid the problem with blums speedup. however, even given that condition its not totally obvious to me that f,g exist & think a proof might not be subtle.