# #SAT Solver download

Tags: ds.algorithms, sat, software

Could anyone please point to one or more websites where is possible to download a working implementation of a #SAT solver? I'm interested in those returning the exact solution count, not an approximation.

Comment: Hi Walter, your question is close to the border of what would be officially "on-topic" for this site. However, if you have nowhere else to ask this question and we can answer it, perhaps it's not that bad... (Since the site is still under development, I think we are being more open than other sites may be.) Rest assured that the point of this comment is not to "scold" or "warn", it is just a friendly notice.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your notice. I'm sorry if this question is close to the border. I've searched on the web and I didn't find anything: only some SAT solvers, but no #SAT solvers. That's why I've asked here. Of course I know that I can write my own code which uses a SAT solver as an engine to count solutions, but I was looking for something already made and ready to use.

Comment: I'd like to disagree. I think such questions are within scope, and should be !

Comment: agree its in scope. fyi/imho its not too practical to build a #SAT solver from a SAT solver unless one has the source code and even in that case, not so practical, except for very small formulas, because of a very bad exponential blowup. usually special techniques unique to #SAT and not SAT would be required...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this with [SAT4J](http://www.sat4j.org/), simply by iterating over all models: http://www.sat4j.org/howto.php#models. I imagine that most SAT solvers have this ability.

Comment: Hi supercooldave, thanks for your pointer. I didn't know that SAT4J had this ability.

Answer (score 16):

You can also try the #SAT solver "sharpSAT" ([website](https://sites.google.com/site/marcthurley/sharpsat), [github](https://github.com/marcthurley/sharpSAT/)) for counting the number of satisfying assignments of CNF formulas.

Answer (score 11):

One option is to use a BDD library, such as [JavaBDD](http://javabdd.sourceforge.net/). All such libraries either have a function that counts solutions fast or, at least, they make it easy to write such a function. The disadvantage, however, is that constructing the BDD will be slow in many cases and may require much memory.

In case your input is in CNF, a simple heuristic that speeds up the construction of the BDD is the following. First, build a small BDD for each clause and put them into a priority queue whose root is the smallest BDD. Second, pop two BDDs, compute AND between them and push the result to the priority queue. Here's the idea: Since computing AND between BDDs of size $m$ and $n$ takes $O(mn)$ in theory but $\sim m+n$ in practice, minimizing the runtime is the same as finding a Huffman code.

Answer (score 8):

The best I found is "c2d compiler". http://reasoning.cs.ucla.edu/c2d/

It uses d-DNNF and you need the **-count** option.

Comment: c2d solves much more CNFs than sharpsat. For _toy_ purposes the "relsat" sat solver will do too.

Answer (score 7):

Related topic: [Best SAT Solver](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1060/873).

Comment: Thanks Sadeq. The topic you indicated seems to be theoretical-oriented. It lists several papers on decreasing the upper bound. It's very interesting, but I was looking for a ready-to-use working implementation.

Comment: You are most welcome. Among the links cited there, there was one which was purely practical: http://www.satcompetition.org/. I think you can find very good implementations there.

Answer (score 7):

The MBound Solver given here http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~sabhar/ can give model counts with probabilistic guarantees. It's much faster than enumerating all solutions.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote a small [model/prime implicant enumerator](http://sat.inesc-id.pt/~mikolas/sw/pienum/). This can already be used for model counting with the model enumeration but that's not very practical. If anybody's interested, I can extend it so it counts models from prime implicants.

Answer (score 3):

The website [BeyondNP](http://beyondnp.org/pages/solvers/model-counters-exact/) contains a good inventory of the existing tools to solve #SAT (and other related hard problems on CNF formulas). You may also find a list of tools for **approximate model counting** and **knowledge compilation** (the task of transforming the CNF into a hopefully succinct data structure that often supports polynomial time model counting).

You may also find a list of tools for **preprocessing** CNF formulas which may be useful to improve the performances of model counters and various **benchmarks**.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is one](https://gitlab.com/kourtis/tensorCSP) called tensorCSP and based on a tool called tensor networks. It is explained in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.00475).

Answer (score 0):

Glucose is a very efficient SAT solver developed at university of Bordeaux.

https://www.labri.fr/perso/lsimon/glucose/