# Implementation of a Logical Hierarchical Hidden Markov Model

Tags: implementation, markov-chains

Is anyone aware of any implementations of algorithms for learning and/or processing a Logical Hierarchical Hidden Markov Model, as described in [this](http://www-kd.iai.uni-bonn.de/pubattachments/260/natarajan08ilp.pdf) paper? I've found dozens of papers about Logical Hidden Markov Models, Hierarchical Hidden Markov Models, and every variation in between, but no one's published any code.

Comment: You could try emailing the authors of the paper.

Comment: I think this is not a TCS question. (Generally asking for implemented code for algorithms is (related but) not a theoretical question. You should ask them on SO.)

Comment: @Kaveh not sure I'd agree with that entirely. I would argue that for more complex algorithms (cf SAT Solvers: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1295/sat-solver-download) it's ok to ask about implementations here, because even implementing such algorithms requires some theoretical insight.

Comment: @Suresh, the question is asking for full code not about the algorithm. I don't see any theoretical point in such a question. The answer is either possible to find by Googling or is simply there is no implementation available. (That question is more like looking for an algorithm than implementation for a particular algorithm.)

Comment: Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this type of question. I would normally ask this on SO, but I've been kicked over here when the question involves new algorithms, so I decided to start here.