# Approximate-#SAT solver

Tags: ds.algorithms, sat, application-of-theory, software

I am looking for a solver that computes an approximation to #SAT.  In other words, given a formula $\phi(x)$ in CNF, approximately count the number of satisfying assignments to $\phi$.  I'm interested in an approximate count, not the exact number.  Are there any existing working implementations that I can download and try?

To be clear, I'm not looking for algorithms or for papers describing algorithms; I'm looking for an implementation I can use, in the style of a SAT solver.  This question is related to [#SAT Solver download](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1295/5038), except that one asks for solvers that exactly count the number of satisfying assignments, whereas I am interested in solvers that approximate the number of satisfying assignments (I do not need an exact count).

Answer (score 2):

[Ashish Sabharwal](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~sabhar/#software) lists some software (e.g., SampleCount, ApproxCount, and more) for this on his web page.  I haven't tried any of these.