# Is SAT in $c^{\sqrt{n}}$ time with preprocessing worthwhile?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat

We may be able to solve SAT in $c^{\sqrt{n}}$ for $n$ variables and a constant $c$.  Now we can suppose that we require a certain amount of preprocessing to get this result.  For example, in [this answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/9656/1549), Ryan Williams points out that we could have a large amount of preprocessing, and SAT in QP (quasi-polynomial) would still be interesting.

So my question is, **if we solve SAT in $c^{\sqrt{n}}$, how much preprocessing can we have and still have an interesting result?**  In other words, if we had something like $2^{2^n}$ preprocessing, would this remain an interesting result?  **Basically, we would be saying that SAT has $c^{\sqrt{n}}$ sized circuits.**

Comment: Basically, what I'm asking is if SAT is already known to have sub-exponential sized circuits.

Comment: While I suppose we _could_ say that SAT is in SUBEXP, we would be wrong. $\:$ See [SUBEXP](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#subexp) and [SE](https://complexityzoo.uwaterloo.ca/Complexity_Zoo:S#se). $\hspace{.25 in}$

Comment: @RickyDemer:  I fixed the question.

Comment: It is conjectured that SAT doesn't have subexponential size circuits (which implies P=BPP), so this will be interesting for an arbitrary preprocessing time.