# Best SAT upper bounds based on number of clauses

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, sat, upper-bounds

What's the best upper bounds based on number of clauses? In [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1060/best-upper-bounds-on-sat) question shown fastest algorithms for SAT, but there bounds depends from number of variables ( $O(const^n)$ where n is number of variables).

I know that variables bounds can be converted to clauses bounds. If k-SAT formula contains $m$ clauses then $n \leq \frac{k * m}{2}$, consequently if algorithm bounded by $O(const^n)$, it also bounded by $O(const^ \frac{k * m}{2}) = O((const^ \frac{k}{2})^m)$. In that way [PPSZ for 3-SAT](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2165) can be bounded by $O(1.496^m)$. But I'm interested in algorithms which bounds "natively" depends from number of clauses.

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22An+algorithm+for+the+SAT+problem+for+formulae+of+linear+length%22 $\;$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's of the order 2^{0.30897m}, see http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~hirsch/abstracts/sodafull.html

(I am not aware of improvements for the number of clauses.)