# Information on k-SAT (Introduction, Bounds, Methods, etc.)

Tags: reference-request, sat, survey

I'd like to know where I can turn for a good, gentle introduction to k-SAT (this may be for mathematicians that may not have a good computer science background).  I'd also like to know papers that maybe survey or explain current methods used to solve k-SAT.  Finally, I'm interested in the best known methods for solving k-SAT.  I'd like to get an idea of the best average case and best worst case behavior.

In short, I'm looking for papers that will help someone in mathematics (not computer science) become much more of an expert in k-SAT.

Comment: There are some good answers about k-SAT on the site: [lecture notes](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/what-lecture-notes-should-everyone-read/4075#4075), [upper](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/1060/1800) and [lower](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/93/1800) bounds, with many links within. Try searching the tag [sat](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sat) also.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Lecture Note reference thread, we have [this document](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/4074/what-lecture-notes-should-everyone-read/4075#4075).

Answer (score 5):

This survey book, [Satisfiability Problem: Theory and Applications](http://www.ams.org/bookstore?fn=50&arg1=salelogic&ikey=DIMACS-35), is appropriate for introducing k-SAT to mathematicians. It is not very recent but still very valuable resource.