# Does this meet the space requirements for the lower 3-SAT bounds?

Tags: sat, lower-bounds

According to ["What are the best current lower bounds on 3SAT?"](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/93/what-are-the-best-current-lower-bounds-on-3sat), Ryan Williams has an answer that states that the (time * space) requirements for 3-SAT must meet or exceed $n^{2 \cos(\pi/7) - o(1)}$ infinitely often.  See

```
 Ryan R. Williams
 Better Time-Space Lower Bounds for SAT and Related Problems
 20th IEEE Conference on Computational Complexity, pages 40-49
 2005
```

...or his link [here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ryanw/automated-lbs.pdf).

If we consider Atkin and Bernstein's sieve:

```
 A.O.L Atkin and D.J. Bernstein
 Prime sieves using binary quadratic forms
 Mathematics of Computation, Volume 73, Number 246, pages 1023-1030
 December 19, 2003
```

...It requires $O(\frac{n}{\log \log n})$ additions and $n^{1/2 + O(1)}$ space.  So does this sieve alone meet the time/space requirements for 3-SAT?  Or are the results inconclusive for the sieve?

Comment: I must be missing something: what does a prime sieve have to do with 3SAT ?

Comment: @SureshVenkat:  I'm working with a residue number system in a 3-SAT algorithm.  I was just wondering if the sieve itself would meet the lower bound requirements.  I now know that the algorithm itself far exceeds the requirements.  I can withdraw the question, if this now seems inappropriate.